# Unable to render image from local path on IOS in ReactNative

Tags: react-native, react-native-image

I am working on a react native application. I am testing it on IOS simulator. I upload images in the application and images get stored on some local path, but when i come back to screen i am unable to show the image, the images space is there but there is no image.

Path where image get stored is:

```
file:///Users/ssi/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/0746958E-03AA-4A38-A208-2CD36B1A484E/data/Containers/Data/Application/628731CA-19CD-497C-8C01-CBC2BA5403B0/Library/Caches/C528D3FF-7153-4D16-9E82-8762AF317780.jpg
```

Code to show the image is:

```js
render() {
  if (this.state.imageData) {
    return (
      <View>
        <View style={styles.view}>
          {
            (this.state.imageData == '' || this.state.imageData == null || this.state.imageData == undefined)
              ?
              null
              :
              this.state.imageData.map(img => {
                var tst = img;
                console.log(img.image.image);

                return (

                  <TouchableHighlight key={this.uuidv4()} onPress={() => {
                    this.setState({ zoom: img.image.image });
                    this.setState({ completeImageObject: img.image });
                  }}>
                    <Image const style={styles.imagePreview} source={{ uri: img.image.image }} />
                  </TouchableHighlight>
                );
              })
          }
        </View>
        {this.state.zoom ? <Card><PinchZoomView scalable={false}><FitImage resizeMode="contain" source={{ uri: this.state.zoom }} /></PinchZoomView>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btn} onPress={() => this.deleteImage(this.state.zoom, this.state.completeImageObject)}>
            <Text style={{ color: 'white' }}>
              Delete Image
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </Card> : <View style={styles.container}><Text>Bild zum vergrößern antippen.</Text></View>}
      </View>

    );
  } else {
    return (<Text style={styles.noIMG}>Keine Bilder vorhanden</Text>)
  }
}
```

Code for uploading image is:

```
ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, (responseIMG) => {

                        if(responseIMG.uri){
                          ImageResizer.createResizedImage(responseIMG.uri, responseIMG.width, responseIMG.height, "JPEG", 10, 0).then((response) => {


                          var answs = this.state.answers ? this.state.answers : [];
                              var dt = new Date();
                              date = (dt.getDate() > 9 ? dt.getDate() : "0" + dt.getDate())
                              + "." + (dt.getMonth() > 9 ? dt.getMonth() : "0" + (dt.getMonth()+1))
                              + "." + dt.getFullYear();

                          var questionIdFromNavigation = this.props.navigation.state.params.q_id;
                          var imageToBeSavedInDb = {a_id: null, content: null, image: response.uri, date: date, p_id: this.state.project.p_id, quest_id: this.props.navigation.state.params.questionnaireId, q_id: questionIdFromNavigation, neu: 1, type:"2", user: em, deleted: 0, local_p_id: this.props.navigation.state.params.project.local_p_id} ;
                              answs.push({
                                  a_id: null,
                                  content: null,
                                  image: response.uri,
                                  date: date,
                                  p_id: this.state.project.p_id,
                                  quest_id: this.props.navigation.state.params.questionnaireId,
                                  q_id: questionIdFromNavigation,
                                  neu: 1,
                                  type:"2",
                                  user: em,
                                  deleted: false,
                                  local_p_id: this.props.navigation.state.params.project.local_p_id});
                                  this.setState({answers: answs});
                                  //saveAns(this.props.navigation.state.params.project, this.state.answers);
                                  db.insertImage(imageToBeSavedInDb, this.props.navigation.state.params.project.local_p_id);
                                  this.setState({loading: false});

                                  var imgs = this.state.images;
                                  if(imgs !== null && imgs !== undefined && imgs !== ''){
                                  imgs.push({image: imageToBeSavedInDb});
                                  this.setState({images: imgs});
                                  }else{
                                    this.setState({images: [{image: imageToBeSavedInDb}]});
                                  }


                  }).catch((err) => {
                     alert(err)
                    });
                        }else{
                          if (responseIMG.didCancel) {

                          }
                          else if (responseIMG.error) {

                          }
                          else {
                          }
                }
                });
```

I do get the above mentioned file path in "img.image.image". There is space for image but there is no image. I also find one more thing that path after the "Application" folder does not exist on my system. Why is that? If path does not exist, how image is stored at that path?

Comment: How is the image uploaded ?

Comment: I have added that code too in the question @Eran

Comment: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-image-picker/issues/107 this might be the issue

Comment: right @Eran i am having the exact issue that my folder gets deleted every time i re-run the application

Comment: @WaleedNaveed I am also having a problem in iOS  (not on android), accessing files stored locally such as file:///data/user/0/com.xxxx/files/productdata_da13681addffaed7622ece9b2bb56e22bc65f6b9.jpg.

I tried to access such files in the browser, couldn't as well.

Any idea?

Comment: @Yossi this path will cause issue in simulator. I would suggest you to check it on real device. BTW i didn't test it on real device because my project requirements changed and i moved to Sqlite. It was very simple and straight forward with Sqlite.

Comment: I tried on a smartphone and I have the same problem.

Comment: @Yossi i am not sure about it then. As my assumption was that simulator will have different path each time but that path would not change in case of smart phone. What about moving to database ? You can easily save image in any format in database.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62626176/unable-to-render-in-react-native-on-ios-images-from-local-path-file-data-use

Answer (score 1):

You should not save the absolute path as it is changing on every build. This issue could be simply solved by replacing the path before "/Documents/..." with a tilde "~".

```
let pathToFile = "file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/9793A9C3-C666-4A0E-B630-C94F02E32BE4/Documents/images/72706B9A-12DF-4196-A3BE-6F17C61CAD06.jpg"
if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
    pathToFile = '~' + pathToFile.substring(pathToFile.indexOf('/Documents'));
}
```

This is supported by React Native as you can see in their [source code](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/23909cd6f62056de0cd0f7c06e3997dd967c139a).